# React form state changes using form name

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, state

handle input changes with react when using arrays in the input name ;

```
handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    });

}
```

this doesn't work if the input name is e.g. `user[email]`, as its got the square array brackets around it. anyone know how its possible to make this generic for string or arrays?

my state is below;

```
this.state =
{

  name: '',
  type: '',
  user: {
    email: '',
   }

};
```

Comment: Why do you need to use user[email] in the input name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nice `this.setState({ [name]: value });` is not really feasible when you have nested state, since it will be difficult to map the name to the actual value.

You could create an additional function e.g. `handleUserInputChange` that sets the value in the `user` state object instead:

```
handleUserInputChange(event) {
    const { target } = event;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const { name } = target;

    this.setState(previousState => {
        return { user: { ...previousState.user, [name]: value } };
    });
}
```